# I don't know how to fix click event on HostListener

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi Guys I'm show one div using **keyup** event. Also using clickoutside event whenever I click keyup event clickoutside event also trigger. Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?.

Used HostListener module.

```
 @HostListener('keyup')
   click(){
     console.log('inside keyup');
    }
 @HostListener('document:click')
 cickout(){
   console.log('clicked outside');
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not quite clear - well at least to me. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Could you give more details in this stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57475064?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: BTW, it seems to be working just as expected

Comment: Actually my question is if I click inside the click event clickout event also trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the clicked element is an input and base your logic on that:

```ts
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
cickout(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName == "INPUT") {
    console.log('input is clicked');
  } else {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

**DEMO: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fkqvzd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Yes, Its good and works well

Comment: great, glad I could help! :)

Comment: Can you share me how to make sample project at stackblitz. I was tried one time but I can't make new service file.

Comment: it's very similar to vs-code, have you used it? Anyway, you can add new files. look at image: https://imgur.com/a/TTUpolw Marked with yellow marker (isn't very clear)

Comment: Thanks, You're helped me lot

Comment: It's working but I need particular div if click it's enable to show if not click that div  going to disable. How to identify it's clicked particular div?

Comment: I would suggests a directive for that :) Here's an article: https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/

Comment: Thanks for giving this wonderful article.

Comment: I have fixed my issue. Thank you so much.